# Is there a way to pass a 16 digit integer? and if so, how can it be done?

Tags: java, object, types, constructor, largenumber

I need to have a user type in a sixteen-digit number (without suffixes or quotes) and then pass that number to an object.  Whenever I attempt to enter such a number, it is considered "datatype int out of range".  I don't want the user to have to enter it as XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL, because the user may not know that java requires an L for `long`s.  I also don't want it to require quotes around the numbers.  Is there a way to convert this before java throws exceptions regarding datatype mismatch or out of range exceptions?

Can this even be done?  I'm trying to construct a `Customer` object that's a field in an `Order` object, which itself is within an `ArrayList<Order> orderList`.  `"Sam Totman"` and the number next to it are examples of the parameters I'm using.

```
    orderList.get(1).setBuyer(new Customer("Sam Totman", 2112112121121121));
```

What should go where I have placed *datatype* in this constructor? `ccn` is credit card number;

```
    public class Customer
    {
        private String name;
        private *datatype* ccn;

        Customer(String name, *datatype* ccn)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.ccn = ccn;
        }
```

Comment: You are confusing numeric literals (which are coded into your programs) with the internal representation.

Comment: Lets assume the input is a Scanner(System.in).  How can this be done?  Will BigInteger datatype work?

Comment: How do you pass an `String` into a `long`? Or how do you get a `long` from a `Scanner`?

Comment: @ReiHinoX Get it as a String. That definitely *doesn't* require the user to enter double quotes around it.

Comment: @ReiHinoX When using `Long.parseLong`, your users do not have to enter `L` at the end of their numerical input in order for it to be parsed as a `long`.

Comment: @ReiHinoX [Scanner.nextLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong%28%29)

Comment: You're not going to do any arithmetic with this 16-digit value, so there's no point having it as any kind of integer.  Just read it as a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orderList.get(1).setBuyer(new Customer("Sam Totman", new Scanner(System.in).nextLong());
```

Comment: Please would you elaborate on your code, showing some explanation of how it solves the provblem. This will help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use scanner to handle input

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
    long aLong = scan.nextLong(10); 
    ....       
    orderList.get(1).setBuyer(new Customer("Sam Totman", aLong));
```

Customer

```
public class Customer
{
    private String name;
    private long ccn;

    Customer(String name, long ccn)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.ccn = ccn;
    }
}
```